# Save a related entry 'on-the-fly' if it does not already exist

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

This seems so simple, yet I can't get my head around how I should do it. I would like to keep a list of 'position' names of employees. So, when entering an employee, I should be able to choose either from a list of positions, or simply enter a new one. In the end I should of course only store the ID of the position in the position table.

Tables would be like this

```
Public Class Position {
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

Public Class Employee {
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get;set;}
    :
    :
    public int PositionID {get;set}
}
```

I think having a type-ahead function which looks up the existing entries as I type, and in case no match is found, I would just post the new position to the position table and somehow get the newly created ID hereof and store this in the employee record. Could this be done - specifically, is there a way to return the key of a newly created record?

Hmm, might have explained myself to a solution - would this be the general way of doing it?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with user1987322 that this may not be the best solution, but in any case:

If you are using the entity framework you simply associate one entity with a related entity. So with your model you would do this:

```
using(var context = new EntityContext())
{
    Employee emp = new Employee()
    {
       LastName = lastName,
       Position = new Position { Name = name }
    };

    context.Employees.AddObject(emp);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

The new Position entity is brought into the context with the new Employee, and the association fix-up is taken care of by the framework.